# Writing Details into a File

Tags: php, file

I am trying to write into a file work/log_file.txt upon submitting a page work/login.php. But the contents (form values from login.php) are not getting written. This is the code I used

```
   if(isset($_POST['submitform'])){
   $file="log_file.txt";
    $open = fopen($file, "a+"); //open the file,

  fwrite($open, "Name: " .$_POST['user'] . "\n"); //print / write the name.
   fwrite($open, "Colour: ". $_POST['color'] . "\n"); //print / write the colour.
   fclose($open); //close the opened file 

  }
```

I am running the code in a test server. I just saved file as log_file.txt in local and then uploaded it to test server folder work ,and run the code. But not getting written to the file

Comment: check permissions to write this file and ckeck php errors

Comment: thx,  I changed the permission of log_file.txt to 777 but still not working

Comment: Make sure you enable display_errors, and set your error_reporting to E_ALL. Something is off, and PHP is not telling you what it is.

Comment: i have to provide error display on login.php right

Comment: look's fine. First I think it should be 'a' not 'a+' at the `fopen` call. And it's very short so try brute force debugging. add to the end of each line 'or die("some message"); and the you know. I suggest something like `$open = fopen($file, "a+") or die("died at 1");
  fwrite($open, "Name: " .$_POST['user'] . "\n") or die("died at 2");` In that way you can know if the code fails at some line and check it. And check if the `isset($_POST['submitform'])` is really set. maybe you just mistyped that name.

Comment: i tried but no use, no errors shown, Actually this login.php page is an ajax page

Answer (score 1):

Does the web server process have write permissions for the file?

Tip that will serve you well: turn on all errors while debugging:

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Any number of things could be off, but you'll never know unless you see the notices and warnings.

Comment: the file operations are written on login.php

Comment: Oh i cannot vote down ,that was not answer ,a comment that's all